# Displaying value of FormControl in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display value of my FormControl in group of radiobuttons, but all i get is [object Object].
My html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <radiobutton-group>
     Food:
    <radiobutton [FormControl]="myForm.get('food')" value="apple"></radiobutton>
    <radiobutton [FormControl]="myForm.get('food')" value="pear"></radiobutton>
    <radiobutton [FormControl]="myForm.get('food')" value="orange"></radiobutton>

  </radiobutton-group>
</form>
<p>Your chosen food is: {{myForm}}</p>
```

And my typescript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './radio-button-food.component.html'
})
export class RadioButtonFoodComponent {
  myForm: any = new FormGroup({
    food: new FormControl('apple'),
    drink: new FormControl('coke'),
  });
 }
```

But i cannot get for example message: "Your chosen food is:apple",
only what i get is "Your chosen food is: [object Object]" or "Your chosen food is: " if i use {{myForm.food}}

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: myForm.food returns the form control, try myForm.food.value

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not work -crushes the app with error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined  at RadioButtonFoodComponent_Template (radio-button-food.component.html:10)

Comment: it means that myForm.food is undefined at the time you are trying to display it. add a *ngIf: <p *ngIf="myForm.food">Your chosen food is: {{myForm.food.value}}</p>

Comment: still does not work.  With that try, whole <p> is not displaying

Comment: Well it works as intended. if the <p> is not displayed it means myForm.food is always undefined.

Comment: Do you know maybe how to change that is always undefined?

Comment: I just realized that you are trying to access a control like it was an object but its not! myForm.food doesnt exist and its not how you can access a formControl. Try usingmyForm.get('food') instead.

Comment: Ahh you are right. It works ! i needed to change it, but still it helped me a lot. That what solved that problem was:
<p>Your choosen is: {{myForm.get('food').value}}</p>

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Im going to post an answer in case someone get the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formGroup is a map so you can't access the formControl like you would with an object. The formControl is not the value but you can access it using myFormControl.value.

- Add an *ngIf otherwise its going to crash on startup
- Use the get function from a map to access the control
- Add value

The quick fix is(That I dont recommend):

```
 <p *ngIf="myForm.get('food')">Your chosen food is: {{myForm.get('food').value}}</p>
```

The better fix would be to subscribe to the form valueChanges and assign a variable with the food value.

ts:

```
const subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
const foodValue = '';
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.add(this.myForm.valueChanges).subscribe((form: any) => {
        this.foodValue = form.food;
    })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

html:

```
<p>Your chosen food is: {{ foodValue }}</p>
```